# facebook graph api with php - share count

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im trying to get wordpress post facebook share count in foreach, but..

```
<?php 

$post_url = the_permalink();
$url_changed = urlencode($post_url);

$json = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url_changed );

ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);


$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['share']['share_count']; 

?>
```

This gives me only to id="" and error

> file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/?id=): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

But if use

```
$json = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com' );
```

Like that, then it works. Does somebody know workaround or how to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

`the_permalink()` displays the current URL and not returning the value, use `get_permalink()` instead..

[Read more about get_permalink() on WP](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Comment: Thank you! Got that working :)! I assumed if im in foreach loop then it is this posts current link. Do you maybe know about fb graph api too? It doesnt show my posts array before i have submitted this link from graph API explorer